# What are drivers in laravel? Eg cache driver

Tags: php, laravel, web, driver

i am reading the laravel documentation but i didnt get about the term about drivers. For example i found that laravel cache is using following drivers

- array
- redis
- file
- apc

so my question is what are drivers? What do we mean by them in case of laravel and why laravel use drivers?
Need simple concept so i can carry on

Comment: "Drivers" are code to connect you (your code) to a subsystem (abstractly spoken). Classically, the driver connects a piece of hardware through a software interface with the operating system.

Comment: so in case of laravel what will be the subsytem???? please give clear concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A driver is an implementation of an interface. For the Caching system, the array driver caches everything in an in-memory array per request. Meaning at the start of each request the cache will be empty.

The file driver implements the caching interface and persists the cache in a file which you can specify in your config.

The redis driver implements the cache interface which persists the cache in a redis database.

etc.

A "cache driver" in Laravel, is a class that implements the contract (interface) [Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Cache/Store.html).

The app does not care what happens beyond calling get or put for example. It is up to the driver to determine what "getting" and "putting" actually means.

Comment: Well spoken ;) Hope the TE accepts your answer...

Comment: ok you are saying A driver is an implementation of an interface.ok  but when i open config/cache.php file i found this   'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ], now acording to your defination cache should be the interface and "apc driver" should be the implementation of cache interface but at the end you are saying   A "cache driver" in Laravel, is a class that implements the contract (interface) its confusing   where is cache driver ?  and where can i find the "APC" class since acording to your defination  it should be implementaion of a cache interface not a cache driver

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Cache/ApcStore.html

Comment: You will see that `class ApcStore extends TaggableStore` and `abstract class TaggableStore implements Store`, where `Store` is `Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store`.

Comment: Also sounds like you are getting confused about several laravel concepts, like facades, the service container and factories. The Caching system uses your config to tell the service container what Cache Store implementation to use when resolving the Store interface out of the container. When no driver is provided to the Cache facade `Cache::get('somekey')` will use the default store specified in your `cache.php` config file. However `Cache::store('array')->get('somekey')` would use the array store, which uses the array driver.

Comment: The stores in the config file tell the cache factory how to configure an instance of the driver. You could create several stores in your config that uses the file driver, and you could specify different files for each of them. So you could do `Cache::store('foo')->put(...)` which it stores it in say `./storage/folderA` and you could do `Cache::store('bar')->put(...)` which stores it in `./storage/folderB` for example. And the config for those would look like `'stores' => [ ... 'foo' => [ 'driver' => 'file', 'path' => storage_path('folderA') ] ... ]`

Comment: i am new to laravel...! and i am searching on the behalf of your answer

Comment: Please accept, as it is the accurate answer to the question provided.

Comment: ok i am going to accept but hope you will come back if i ask the questions again on your answer

Comment: That is not how Stack Overflow works. You ask new questions for new questions.

Comment: yes i know but i am asking specific to your answer friend

Comment: hi mate  can you recomment a channel to learn basic concepts behind facades, service providers and overall architecture.?  I learned many things but i just want to know more magic .shall be thankfull to you in this act of kindness

Comment: laracasts.com is by far the best resource, and well worth the subscription.